# In CAS Overlay, How to send user attributes

Tags: cas

In CAS Overlay, How to return user attributes other than name to the clients in JAVA. I am using CAS Overlay project and storing the user details in Database.

Comment: There are many options here. So, you better provide more details as what auth provider is used. If it is jdbc it would be rather simple. If it is ldap or any other than jdbc that would be more complicated. There are several config points for client application as well. Can you pleas provide application configuration here?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I am able to fetch the User Attributes of the Logged in User from the CAS Server to the client.

I am using CAS Overlay project version 5.0.0.RC1 and Spring Security 4.1.3.RELEASE.

Spring Client Configuration in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
 @Bean
public ServiceProperties serviceProperties() {
    ServiceProperties serviceProperties = new ServiceProperties();
    serviceProperties.setService(serviceUrl);
    serviceProperties.setSendRenew(false);
    return serviceProperties;
}

@Bean
public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {
    CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
    casAuthenticationProvider.setAuthenticationUserDetailsService(authenticationUserDetailsService());
    casAuthenticationProvider.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
    casAuthenticationProvider.setTicketValidator(cas30ServiceTicketValidator());
    casAuthenticationProvider.setKey("an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only");
    return casAuthenticationProvider;
}

@Bean
public Cas30ServiceTicketValidator cas30ServiceTicketValidator() {
    return new Cas30ServiceTicketValidator(casServer);
}


@Bean
public AuthenticationUserDetailsService authenticationUserDetailsService(){
    String[] role ={"user_role"};
    return new GrantedAuthorityFromAssertionAttributesUserDetailsService(role);
}



@Bean
public CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
    casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
    casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler());
    return casAuthenticationFilter;
}

@Bean
public CasAuthenticationEntryPoint casAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
    CasAuthenticationEntryPoint casAuthenticationEntryPoint = new CasAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setLoginUrl(casServerLogin);
    casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
    return casAuthenticationEntryPoint;
}

@Bean
public LogoutFilter requestSingleLogoutFilter (){

    LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter(casLogout,new SecurityContextLogoutHandler());
    logoutFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/j_spring_cas_security_logout");
    return logoutFilter;
}

@Bean
public SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter() {
    SingleSignOutFilter filter = new SingleSignOutFilter();
    filter.setCasServerUrlPrefix(casServer);
    filter.setIgnoreInitConfiguration(true);
    return filter;
}
```

Configured the Database attribute repository on the CAS Server side as I was storing the user details in Database.

```
<code>
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.singleRow=true
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.requireAllAttributes=true
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.caseCanonicalization=NONE
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.queryType=OR

cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.sql=SELECT * FROM users  WHERE {0}
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.username=username
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.healthQuery=SELECT 1
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.isolateInternalQueries=false
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/casdb
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.failFast=true
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.isolationLevelName=ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.leakThreshold=10
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.propagationBehaviorName=PROPAGATION_REQUIRED
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.batchSize=1
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.user=postgres
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.ddlAuto=update
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.password=postgres
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.autocommit=false
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.driverClass=org.postgresql.Driver
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.idleTimeout=5000
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.pool.suspension=false
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.pool.minSize=6
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.pool.maxSize=18
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.pool.maxIdleTime=1000
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc.pool.maxWait=2000

cas.authn.attributeRepository.attributes.last_name=last_name
cas.authn.attributeRepository.attributes.first_name=first_name
cas.authn.attributeRepository.attributes.user_role=user_role 

</code>
```

After these changes I was able to fetch the user attributes from CAS Server.